# Allowed to connect to predefined wifi networks

Tags: wireless-networking, blocking

I need a software or solution to forbid to connect any not predefined WI-FI network for the users on windows 10. The goal is simple, I defined our company WIFI settings and some others and if the user wanted to connect any other Wi-Fi network, like in a hotel or at home it would be blocked.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We will need more information in order to help you. What system (OS) are your target computers using? How did you define the WiFi settings? How do you want to enforce the restriction (i.e. is installing additional software OK)? What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Not sure if letting users bring their work PCs to home, but forbidding internet access, will do you any good. Maybe you need the Direct Access always-on VPN feature instead?

Comment: [You can use a group policy to configure a wireless connection.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg266419.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: The target OS is Windows 10. Regarding define WIFI connection I don't have any exact idea. For example with an administrator user I add the allowed WI-FI settings, SSID, and password. and the user (not administrator) can connect only these WI-FI network.

Comment: Regarding VPN, the goal is different what VPN can provide.

Comment: Ramhound, that is what I need. However this laptops are not in domain. I hope via registry this solution is possible, too.

Comment: I found a link which worth a test:
http://blog.defron.org/2013/02/locking-down-wifi-on-windows-without.html

Comment: What is a target goal? Disable network access? there're still possibility to use ethernet port (or use ethernet over USB) or similar network devices (connect raspberry pi over USB in gadget mode and emulate your working environment to get out of jail)

Comment: You are right, this rule will be for simle users who even don't have lan cable at home :) I just organise the task, it was not defined by me.